# Make a blade layout only appear when the users selects from a dropdown using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, dropdown

**Note : I am using Laravel**

This is my dropdown and what I want to be able to update my php variable which is stored in my database   `$SetNewMatch = Auth::user()->dailyMatch;`

```
                             <form>
                              <select name = "dailyMatch">
                                  <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
                                  <option value="Classical">Classical</option>
                                  <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
                              </select>
                                  <button type="submit">
                                  {{ __('Submit') }}
                                  </button>
                             </form>
```

Once the user submits a value by pressing the submit button , I want a boolean variable to also update to true ,  so `$book  = true`.

Once the user has selected value from the dropdown  and the boolean value is true. I want the blade layout will appear or even a Div class will appear.

I've tried the below but its not displaying

```
<?php 
if ($book == true)
{
    @include 'layouts.divAPIclass');
} 
else
{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

I know this is a lot but if you have any questions just ask. If you have any better ways in doing this please suggest. Thanks

Comment: You can use `@includeWhen($book == true, 'layouts.divAPIclass')` in your blade. It has a third parameter, if you want to pass some data

Comment: Thanks this is useful however how do I make $book = true , when I submit my form? @LeventeOtta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got options for this. I don't know what your routes file looks like, but I'm going to assume you have the following in your web routes file.

```
Route::post('/your/route', 'MatchController@update')->name('dailyMatch');
```

**Option #1:**
*Redirect to a named route*

Your blade that the form is on:

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/route">
    @csrf 
    <select name="dailyMatch" id="dailyMatch" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="classical">Classical</option>
    </select>
</form> 


@if( $book == true )
    @include('layouts.divAPIclass')
@endif
```

Your MatchController:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $dailyMatch = $request->dailyMatch;
    // process your data
    ... 

   // then redirect back with your boolean value 
    return redirect()->route('routenamehere', [
        'book' => true,
        'dailyMatch' => $dailyMatch
    ]);
}
```

**Option #2:**
*Take advantage of laravels back() helper*

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/route">
    @csrf 
    <select name="dailyMatch" id="dailyMatch" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="classical">Classical</option>
    </select>
</form> 

@if( session('dailyMatchUpdated') )
    @include('layouts.divAPIclass')
@endif
```

Your MatchController:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $dailyMatch = $request->dailyMatch;
    // Process your dailyMatch data
    ... 

    // Then use the back() function 
    return back()->with('dailyMatchUpdated', 'You selected a new match');
}
```

**Option #3:**
*Redirect to a controller action*

If you are navigating to the original form page via a controller action, I would suggest to go this route

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/route">
    @csrf 
    <select name="dailyMatch" id="dailyMatch" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="classical">Classical</option>
    </select>
</form> 

@if( $book == true )
    @include('layouts.divAPIclass')
@endif
```

Your MatchController:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $dailyMatch = $request->dailymatch;
    // Process your data 
    ... 

    // Then redirect to the original controller action and pass it the book value 
    return redirect()->action('SomeController@someFunction', ['book' => true]);

}
```

Hopefully this helps you out!